# Symfony - Select object where date = today

Tags: mysql, symfony, date, select, where-clause

I have a entity repository containing code

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('tdd');
$qb->select('tdd')
->where($qb->expr()->eq('tdd.disable_date', ':dat'))
->setParameter('dat', new \DateTime());
return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

And Entity containing only one member (disable_date)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", unique=true, nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id()
 */
private $disable_date;
```

When I try to check if today's date is in database, code above returns NULL.
Date in DB exists.
What the heck?

Comment: Try to change type= "date" to type="datetime"

Comment: I can't. I need only date. When I will change type to datetime I will need to get Today by using BETWEEN in query. In my case I'm just searching for date existing in DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `new DateTime()` creates object similar to this:

`object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-04-12 07:24:34.697668"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(10) "US/Pacific"
}`

And you trying to match exact date with time (including `seconds` and `ms`). And thats why results is `null`

Check date without `h:i:s`

Comment: Your aswer was right. I checked that option earlier by using date('Y-m-d') instead of DateTime but I didn't saw another problem - My entity had Date as an Id and that was a problem, Doctrine can't cast DT into string to get is as Id. I added standard $Id member and everything works like a charm. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using midnight modificator.

When you declare in doctrine a Date field, in database it will be stored as date time, but Entity uses a DateTime interface.

So if you try to compare a new \DateTime (current date and time) with the date stored en database, parsed by doctrine as date stored + current time, comparasion never will be equal.

Using the midnight modificator you are really comparing equals.

```
$dateInDatabase = '2020-04-22'; 

$parsedByDoctrine = new \DateTime($dateInDatabase); // 2020-04-22 00:00:00 
$now = new \DateTime(); // 2020-04-22 17:20:00 
$todayMidnight = new \DateTime('midnight'); // 2020-04-22 00:00:00 

$now === $parsedInDatabase // FALSE 
$todayMidnight === $parsedInDatabase // TRUE
```

This can be applied in the createQueryBuilder or in the findBy methods

[php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what is a "midnight modificator"?

Comment: Please add all explanation **to the answer by editing it**

Comment: Sorry, it's my first day :P

Comment: You're welcome - thanks for editing your answer and providing more details!